# Getting "maximum redirect" when upgrading to nginx 3.11.1

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, ingress-nginx

I have a Kubernetes cluster running in AWS, and I am working through upgrading various components.  Internally, we are using NGINX, and it is currently at `v1.1.1` of the `nginx-ingress` chart (as served from [old stable](https://charts.helm.sh/stable)), with the following configuration:

```
controller:
  publishService:
    enabled: "true"
  replicaCount: 3
  service:
    annotations:
      external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: '*.MY.TOP.LEVEL.DOMAIN'
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: [SNIP]
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    targetPorts:
      http: http
      https: http
```

My service's ingress resource looks like...

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
  [SNIP]
spec:
  rules:
  - host: MY-SERVICE.MY.TOP.LEVEL.DOMAIN
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: MY-SERVICE
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - hostname: [SNIP]
```

This configuration works just fine, however, when I upgrade to `v3.11.1` of the `ingress-nginx` chart (as served from [the k8s museum](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx)).

With an unmodified config, curling to the HTTPS scheme redirects back to itself:

```
curl -v https://MY-SERVICE.MY.TOP.LEVEL.DOMAIN/INTERNAL/ROUTE
*   Trying W.X.Y.Z...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to MY-SERVICE.MY.TOP.LEVEL.DOMAIN (W.X.Y.Z) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.MY.TOP.LEVEL.DOMAIN
*  start date: Aug 21 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 20 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "MY-SERVICE.MY.TOP.LEVEL.DOMAIN" matched cert's "*.MY.TOP.LEVEL.DOMAIN"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET INTERNAL/ROUTE HTTP/1.1
> Host: MY-SERVICE.MY.TOP.LEVEL.DOMAIN
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Wed, 28 Apr 2021 19:07:57 GMT
< Location: https://MY-SERVICE.MY.TOP.LEVEL.DOMAIN/INTERNAL/ROUTE
< Content-Length: 164
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host MY-SERVICE.MY.TOP.LEVEL.DOMAIN left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

(I wish I had captured more verbose output...)

I tried modifying the NGINX config to append the following:

```
config:
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
```

and then...

```
config:
  compute-full-forwarded-for: "true"
  use-forwarded-headers: "true"
```

These did not seem to make a difference.  It was in the middle of the day, so I wasn't able to dive too far in before rolling back.

What should I look at, and how should I debug this?

**Update:**

I wish that I had posted a complete copy of the updated config, because I would have noticed that I did *not* correctly apply the change to add `config.compute-full-forwarded-for: "true"`.  It need to be within the `controller` block, and I had placed it elsewhere.

Once the `compute-full-forwarded-for: "true"` config was added, everything started to work immediately.

Comment: What happens if you curl with -L option, following redirects? Does it keeps permanent redirecting you?

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As confirmed by @object88 the issue was with misplaced `config.compute-full-forwarded-for: "true"` configuration which was located in the wrong block. Adding it to the `controller` block solved the issue.